# Netflix on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, netflix

I'm about to buy the all new BQ tablet with ubuntu touch.

Is there any way to watch netflix on ubuntu touch? I Know, the ubuntu desktop can easily stream netflix using chrome, but as far as I know, chrome is not an option on ubuntu touch.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

As of 2016-06-13, the only mean to watch Netflix on Linux is through Chrome.  If Chrome is not available in your distribution, you cannot watch Netflix.  Since Chrome is not available for Linux ARM, you cannot watch Netflix on any ARM devices, including pretty much all devices Ubuntu Touch is actively worked on.  Note that one can get a Ubuntu Touch image for x86 systems [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/).

Chrome comes with the *Widevine* extension which Netflix use.  This extension complies with [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions).  Google acquired the technology on December 3, 2010 by buying *[Widevine Technologies inc](https://www.widevine.com/)*.

There was a campaign on [Indiegogo](https://www.indiegogo.com) named [World's First True made for Linux/Ubuntu x86/x64 Tablet](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/world-s-first-true-linux-x86-and-x64-tablet#/) where an Intel tablet is proposed.  Since it was Intel based, Chrome should have worked on it.  But alas, the campaign failed to raise the money.

Comment: Hm, watching Netflix on Chrome here without any "proprietary extension" (that I would have had to install manually). It's just plain HTML5. The only reason that only Chrome works is because of the content is DRM-encrypted. Otherwise, I agree - the only ways of getting Netflix to work on Linux is through either Chrome or Pipelight, neither of which supports ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Netflix says that Firefox 42 or later should also work, but I assume that it's only on the desktop. I will try Firefox on Ubuntu Touch as well on my Bq Aquaris M10 (it doesn't work in the Ubuntu browser on the M10, tried that already to no avail).
https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742

Edit: doesn't work in Firefox on Ubuntu Touch either :(